Calculations inconsistency in the calculation of values for different time frames
I am looking to use pinescript to calculate Ehler's instantaneous Trendlines in two different time frame (3m and 15 m). 3m is the chart time frame. The code base i am using it by a pretty prolific pinescript coder LazyBear. The link for the code is https://www.tradingview.com/script/DaHLcICg-Ehlers-Instantaneous-Trend-LazyBear/
As the code is old, i have modified the code slightly and i am looking to plot two sets of EIT bands, one which is calculated in the current time frame and the other in the 15 minute timeframe.
The code for calculation of Ehlers instantaneous Trendline:
// Ehlers Instantaneous Trendline function
eit(src, alpha) =>
    var float it =0.0
    it := (alpha - ((alpha * alpha) / 4.0)) * src +
         (0.5 * alpha * alpha) * src[1] -
         (alpha - 0.75 * alpha * alpha) * src[2] +
         2 * (1 - alpha) * nz(it[1], ((src + 2 * src[1] + src[2]) / 4.0)) -
         (1 - alpha) * (1 - alpha) * nz(it[2], ((src + 2 * src[1] + src[2]) / 4.0))
    it


And code for the input parameters, bands(areas between the EIT and the trigger line):
// Input parameters
src  = input(ohlc4, title="Source")
src2 = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "15", ohlc4)
alpha1 = input.float(0.01, title="Alpha1", step=0.01)
alpha2 = input.float(0.01, title="Alpha1 - 15m TF", step=0.01)


//Zones setup -3m
show_zone1 = input.bool(true, title="Show Zone-1 color fill?")
transparency1 = input.int(65, title="fill transparency", minval=0, maxval=100)
fill_color_1_dn = input(color.rgb(255, 0,  0, 30), title="Fill Color 1-down")
fill_color_1_up = input(color.rgb(0, 255, 0, 30), title="Fill Color 1-up")

//Zones setup for TF-15 min
show_zone15_1 = input.bool(false, title="Show Zone-151 (15m) color fill?")
transparency15_1 = input.int(20, title="fill transparency", minval=0, maxval=100)
fill_color_151_dn = input(color.rgb(255, 0,  0, 30), title="Fill Color 151-down")
fill_color_151_up = input(color.rgb(0, 255, 0, 30), title="Fill Color 151-up")

and the calculations for the EIT and Trigger values:
eit_value1 = eit(src, alpha1)
eit_value15 =eit(src2, alpha2)

//Trigger line calculation (lag of 2 periods)
lag1 =2.0 * eit_value1 - nz(eit_value1[2])
lag2 =2.0 * eit_value15 - nz(eit_value15[2])

I am taking these values and plotting them in the chart but when plotted, these are coming as overlapping on each other. I created a table to see which values are coming, and i was surprised to find that the set of values coming are nearly same. This cannot be as I checked the display of the values in 15m time frame and the values are coming different.
I understand that there might be some differences in the values but here it is not the case. The values for the src2 (calculated using request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "15", ohlc4) is obviously not working as I intended.
My question is:
What should i do now to correct the code so the values are approximate and there is some reconcilation of the values and hence the plots as well?
Thank you for reading my question.

Try f_security of this library
src  = input(ohlc4, title="Source")
alpha1 = input.float(0.01, title="Alpha1", step=0.01)
i_htf = input.timeframe ('15', 'Select Higher Timeframe')
i_repaint = input.bool (false, '■ Repaint On/Off')

eit(src, alpha) =>
    var float it =0.0
    it := (alpha - ((alpha * alpha) / 4.0)) * src +
         (0.5 * alpha * alpha) * src[1] -
         (alpha - 0.75 * alpha * alpha) * src[2] +
         2 * (1 - alpha) * nz(it[1], ((src + 2 * src[1] + src[2]) / 4.0)) -
         (1 - alpha) * (1 - alpha) * nz(it[2], ((src + 2 * src[1] + src[2]) / 4.0))
    it

f_security(_symbol, _res, _src, _repaint) =>
  request.security(_symbol, _res, _src[_repaint ? 0 : barstate.isrealtime ? 1 : 0])
                                      [_repaint ? 0 : barstate.isrealtime ? 0 : 1]

eit_value1 = f_security(syminfo.tickerid, i_htf, eit(src, alpha1 ), i_repaint)
lag1 =2.0 * eit_value1 - nz(eit_value1[2])

plot(eit_value1, color = color.red)
plot(lag1, color = color.blue)


Thank you for your suggestion. Though useful, it does not serve my purpose.  What I really want to do is to be able to plot the ribbons in a single chart with reference to the both time frames (3m and 15m). I hope this further clarifies my query.
